# Pass resolve to body controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hello ive got something like this

```
<body ng-app="app" id="ng-app" ng-controller="MasterCtrl">
```

and some views which need master controller to resolve some data

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

im using ui-router
how to pass resolve to masterctrl?
if i try something like doing the master state at '/' in state configuration i dont get master resolved when urling to children

Comment: Can you provide some code from your $stateProvider?

Comment: It might be better to specify the controller in the states too rather than in the body tag

Answer (score 0):

So, you're resolving something in your controller(s).. [let's use 'user']

```
    .state('myCoolState', {
        url: baseURL + 'coolState/:id',
        templateUrl: baseURL + 'Scripts/Templates/CoolStateView.html',
        controller: 'coolStateController',
        title: 'MyCoolState.com',
        resolve: {
            user : function (userService) {
                return userService.getUser();
            }
        }
    })
```

and it's working great.. but now you want to resolve user in your master controller..

What works for me is, with a factory like:

```
.factory("userService", function ($q, $http, baseURL) {
    return {
        getUser: function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({
                url: baseURL + 'api/User/',
                method: "GET"
            })
           .then(function (result) {
               deferred.resolve(result.data.data);
           });
           return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
});
```

I just inject my userService into the master controller

```
MasterCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$location', '$rootScope', '$state', '$http', 'baseURL', 'userService'];
```

with my master controller defined as

```
var MasterCtrl = function ($scope, $location, $rootScope, $state, $http, baseURL, user) {
  user.getUser().then(function() {
    //stuff where you need access to user
    //this won't happen until 'user' is resolved
  });
};
```

It'd be nice to resolve user outside of the masterCtrl definition.. so it looked cleaner.. as far as I know you can't do that.